# Why my Cocoa WebView can't display browse file dialog box?

Tags: cocoa, webview

I am creating a [custom browser](http://odeskdesktop.swdevbali.com) that only display certain web site (oDesk and Trello).

[image: Custom browser]

I use Web View to display it, embedded it in a tab control. But I realize now, that if it requires a file attachment, it didn't display browse file dialog box.

Is there any work around for this?
Or, is this the limitation of a WebView controller?

EDITED:
I've check this, and it occur in any site (well, just testing gmail and [odesk](http://www.odesk.com) actually) that require a file attachment. When I click it, nothing happen. No browse dialog open. This two pictures of it :
oDesk attachment:
[image: oDesk]

Gmail attachment:

[image: GMail]

EDITED
This is the code that load relevant website:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[webViewOdesk mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.odesk.com"]]];
    [[webViewTrello mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://trello.com"]]];
    [[webViewGmail mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gmail.com"]]];
    [[webViewGoogle mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];

    [window setReleasedWhenClosed:NO]; 
}
```

I have add two more websites here : gmail and google

Comment: Can you post a full screenshot of what you have right now and what it should look like?  (And if possible, give us the link to the specific link to that site)

Comment: actually, I can stay that there's no code at all involved. I just add a WebView controller, connect it to relevant property in the app Delegate and some code in the init. Wait, I'll just paste that by the way :D

Answer (score 0):

OSX webkit doesn't implement browser panel for you by default, you need set UI delegate and make it by yourself.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener:(id < WebOpenPanelResultListener >)resultListener
{
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];

    // process the files.

    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
    {
        NSArray* URLs = [openDlg URLs];
        for (int i = 0; i <[URLs count]; i++) {
            NSString *filename = [[URLs objectAtIndex:i]relativePath];
            [resultListener chooseFilename:filename];
        }
    }

}
```